# loading bootstrap inside php echo

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm new to php this is my php code and it is working fine in the normal html code. but when it is loading from the php echo bootstrap grid is not working any help ? other css is loading correctly.

```
<?php
echo"<html>";
echo"   <head>";
echo"      <link href='css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>";
echo"   </head>";
echo"   <body>";
echo"      <div class='container-fluid'>";
echo"         <div class='row'>";
echo"            <div class='col-md-12'>";
echo"               <h3 class='text-center text-primary'>PHP Form Builder</h3>";
echo"               <div class='row'>";
echo"                  <div class='col-md-6'>";
echo"                     <div class='panel panel-primary'>";
echo"                        <div class='panel-heading'>";
echo"                           <h3 class='panel-title'>Components</h3>";
echo"                        </div>";
echo"                        <div class='panel-body'>";
echo"                           <label class='col-md-4 control-label' for='input01'>Text input</label>";
echo"                           <input id='txt_textInput' type='text' placeholder='title' class='form-control input-md'>";
echo"                           <p class='help-block'></p>";
echo"                           <button id='btn_textInput' type='button' class='col-md-4 btn btn-info'>Add</button> ";
echo"                        </div>";
echo"                        <div class='panel-footer'></div>";
echo"                     </div>";
echo"                     <button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-block'>Reset Form</button>";
echo"                  </div>";
echo"                  <div class='col-md-6'>";
echo"                     <div class='panel panel-info'>";
echo"                        <div class='panel-heading'>";
echo"                           <h3 class='panel-title'>From Preview</h3>";
echo"                        </div>";
echo"                        <div class='panel-body'>";
echo"                        </div>";
echo"                        <div class='panel-footer'></div>";
echo"                     </div>";
echo"                     <button type='button' class='btn btn-block btn-success'>Save</button>";
echo"                  </div>";
echo"               </div>";
echo"            </div>";
echo"         </div>";
echo"      </div>";
echo"      <script src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>";
echo"   </body>";
echo"</html>";
?>
```

Comment: path is ok and everything should be from raw php

Comment: I can't read all your tag atm, but please, if you have no vars in your html, please don't use `echo`. Just use pure html.

Comment: @MaxExplode solved :) !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is working fine, when i change the src of script, and src of css, i am sure you must have error in path.

see code.

```
<?php
echo"<html>";
echo"   <head>";
echo"      <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet'>";
echo"   </head>";
echo"   <body>";
echo"      <div class='container-fluid'>";
echo"         <div class='row'>";
echo"            <div class='col-md-12'>";
echo"               <h3 class='text-center text-primary'>PHP Form Builder</h3>";
echo"               <div class='row'>";
echo"                  <div class='col-md-6'>";
echo"                     <div class='panel panel-primary'>";
echo"                        <div class='panel-heading'>";
echo"                           <h3 class='panel-title'>Components</h3>";
echo"                        </div>";
echo"                        <div class='panel-body'>";
echo"                           <label class='col-md-4 control-label' for='input01'>Text input</label>";
echo"                           <input id='txt_textInput' type='text' placeholder='title' class='form-control input-md'>";
echo"                           <p class='help-block'></p>";
echo"                           <button id='btn_textInput' type='button' class='col-md-4 btn btn-info'>Add</button> ";
echo"                        </div>";
echo"                        <div class='panel-footer'></div>";
echo"                     </div>";
echo"                     <button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-block'>Reset Form</button>";
echo"                  </div>";
echo"                  <div class='col-md-6'>";
echo"                     <div class='panel panel-info'>";
echo"                        <div class='panel-heading'>";
echo"                           <h3 class='panel-title'>From Preview</h3>";
echo"                        </div>";
echo"                        <div class='panel-body'>";
echo"                        </div>";
echo"                        <div class='panel-footer'></div>";
echo"                     </div>";
echo"                     <button type='button' class='btn btn-block btn-success'>Save</button>";
echo"                  </div>";
echo"               </div>";
echo"            </div>";
echo"         </div>";
echo"      </div>";
echo"      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>";
echo"   </body>";
echo"</html>";
?>
```

please check and let me know.

Thanks
Amit